# Angular. Static convert template of Component before component compilation?

Tags: angular

Is a way to convert template of component form that way?

`<input paramName="BSD" paramDisabled>` => `<input [(ngModel)]="context.model.value.BSD" [disabled]="context.model.idisabled.BSD">`

or

`<input paramName="BSD" paramDisabled paramWarning>` => `<div class="warning"><input [(ngModel)]="context.model.value.BSD" [disabled]="context.model.idisabled.BSD"></div>`

There are Checkboxes and selectors too.

As you can see it is a static convert from source template to result. I have a form with 100-200 params (don't ask why. It is job of my employer in building area)

I use AngularJS before and this was very simple to do that dynamically/programmatically. New Angular do not allow that way directly. But this is a just static conversion of source template. May be exists some tools or another way to precompile templates to new Angular template?

Comment: you can provide a loader that would analyze your code and transform it. but nobody does that as it is just breaks many other things, like ide syntax highlights, linting tools and so on... . in your place I would mass replace `<input paramName...` to `<app-input paramName...` and would've built component that would handle those params for you

Comment: @Andrei Wish I do this with [(ngModel)]. I wish to transfer attribute value to [(ngModel)] path. As I know the [(ngModel)] is static field and one cannot be changed programmatically?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean. `[(ngMode)]="value"` is exactly the same as writing `[ngModel]="value" (ngModel)="value = $event"`

Comment: @Andrei Is it possible to transfer path to ngModel value as attribute value?
`<input paramName="BSD" paramDisabled paramWarning>` =>

`<div class="warning"><input [(ngModel)]="context.model.value.<paramName>" [disabled]="context.model.idisabled.<paramName>"></div>`